# How can I get the name of the class that throws a custom made Exception

Tags: java, custom-exceptions

I'm preparing a project for college where I need to write a custom made exception that will be thrown by a couple of classes in the same package when they were not initialized properly. The problem is that I must let the user know which of those classes wasn't initialized properly (and throwed the exception)... So I was thinking about something like this:

```
class InitializationException extends Exception {

private static final String DEFAULT_MSG =
            "This " + CLASSNAME-THROWINGME + " had not been initialized properly!";

    protected String msg;

InitializationException() {
    this.msg = DEFAULT_MSG;
}

    InitializationException(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
}
```

(btw, can it be achieved via reflection?)

Comment: You could extend `Exception` and add a field for the `.class` if the causing type.

Comment: Or you could make an exception for each class...

Comment: Also, reflection is almost certainly not a good idea here.

Comment: Look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [`Throwable.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29). Each `StackTraceElement` has [`getClassName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getClassName%28%29). You can look at element `[0]` to determine the origination of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
StackTraceElement[] trace = theException.getStackTrace();
String className = trace[0].getClassName();
```

(Though I'm not quite sure whether you want the first element or the last in the trace.)

(And note that you can create a Throwable and do getStackTrace() on it, without ever throwing it, to find out who called you (which would be trace element 1).)

Comment: You want the first one. The API says 'The zeroth element of the array (assuming the array's length is non-zero) represents the top of the stack, which is the last method invocation in the sequence. Typically, this is the point at which this throwable was created and thrown'

Comment: @DilumRanatunga - Yeah, I'd have figured it out but I was racing to beat you.  Didn't succeed, though.

Comment: Nice tip about the unthrown `Throwable`. Answers the age old question "If an exception is instantiated but never thrown, was there really an exception?" The answer is "only if you called getStackTrace() to acknowledge its existence" :)

Answer (score 1):

I would just pass the throwing class into the constructor, like this:

```
public class InitializationException extends Exception {

    public InitializationException(Class<?> throwingClass) { ... }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class InitializationException extends Exception {
    private final String classname;
    InitializationException(String msg, Object origin) {
        super(msg);
        this.classname = origin != null ? origin.getClass().toString() : null;
    }
    public String getClassname() {
        return this.classname;
    }
}
```

. . . .
    throw new InitializationException("Something went wrong", this);

Answer (score 0):

Its a workaround:

you could pass the classname within the Constructor, something like

```
throw new  InitializationException(getClass().getName());
```

or may be  call the class like

```
throw new InitializationException(this);
```

and handle the name extraction in your excpetin class

```
 InitializationExcpetion(Object context){ 
this.name = getClass().getName() 
}
```

Comment: `getEnclosingClass()` is used for inner classes. If the class constructing the exception is not an inner class, this will be `null`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingClass()

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you force the class throwing the exception to tell the exception which class it is:

```
public class InitializationException extends Exception {

    public InitializationException(Class<?> c) {
        super( "The class " + c.getName()+ " had not been initialized properly!");
    }
}
```